# How to fill range of cells with same value using formula?

Tags: google-sheets

I use this :

```
={0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0}
```

and it fill the range (4 columns and 3 rows) like this :

[image]

Is there any formula so i can fill it automatically?

For example start at cell A1 and fill 100 rows and 100 column with value 0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

`=SEQUENCE(100,100,0,0)`

This reads "Fill 100 rows and 100 columns with a sequence that starts at zero and increments by zero."

Comment: Note: the SEQUENCE function works only with integers without decimal. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244?hl=en

Comment: That is not what the poster asked. And these days, most would recommend the newer function anyway, which can handle any input: `=MAKEARRAY(15, 6, LAMBDA(x, y, 0))` 0r `=MAKEARRAY(15, 6, LAMBDA(x, y, 2.16))` or `=MAKEARRAY(15, 6, LAMBDA(x, y, "cat"))` etc.